# How to store File Location in ButtonClick based on Combobox Selection records?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created the combobox that linked to the textboxes. What I want is to display the File Location by clicking button OpenFile based on the combobox selection(each record in combobox has its own file location). For example, if I select Record1 from combobox the (C:\Users\Maryam\Downloads\SUB-CON DATA.xlsx) location will be stored in the button called OpenFile.
If I select Record2, this location (C:\Users\Maryam\Desktop\09-SEP -2020.xlsx) will be stored in the button called OpenFile. And so on for other records.

[The mainwindow display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzzfH.png)

> The mainwindow.cs.xaml code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;

namespace BV_Desktop
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-7J69E9N;Initial Catalog=DatabaseInfor;Integrated Security=True");


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            fillcombobox();
            DisplayData();

        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           comboBox1.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        public void fillcombobox()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-7J69E9N;Initial Catalog=DatabaseInfor;Integrated Security=True");
            string sql = "Select * from Tb_Sub";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            SqlDataReader myreader;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (myreader.Read())
                {
                    string sname = myreader.GetString(1);
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(sname);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-7J69E9N;Initial Catalog=DatabaseInfor;Integrated Security=True");
            string sql = "Select * from Tb_Sub where (Subcontractor)='" + comboBox1.SelectedItem+ "';";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            SqlDataReader myreader;

            try
            {
                SubID.Text = string.Empty;
                txtClients.Text = string.Empty;
                txtDetails.Text = string.Empty;
                txtPO.Text = string.Empty;
                txtScope.Text = string.Empty;
                txtProjectNo.Text = string.Empty;
                txtZIG.Text = string.Empty;
                txtAmount.Text = string.Empty;
                txtInvoiceDate.Text = string.Empty;
                txtStatus.Text = string.Empty;

                conn.Open();
                myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (myreader.Read())
                {
                    string id = myreader.IsDBNull(0) ? null : myreader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                    string clients = myreader.IsDBNull(2) ? null : myreader.GetString(2);
                    string contactdetails = myreader.IsDBNull(3) ? null : myreader.GetString(3);
                    string ponum = myreader.IsDBNull(4) ? null : myreader.GetString(4);
                    string scope = myreader.IsDBNull(5) ? null : myreader.GetString(5);
                    string projectno = myreader.IsDBNull(6) ? null : myreader.GetString(6);
                    string zigno = myreader.IsDBNull(7) ? null : myreader.GetInt32(7).ToString();
                    string amount = myreader.IsDBNull(8) ? null : myreader.GetSqlMoney(8).ToString();
                    string invoicedate = myreader.IsDBNull(9) ? null : myreader.GetDateTime(9).ToShortDateString();
                    string status = myreader.IsDBNull(10) ? null : myreader.GetString(10).ToString();

                    SubID.Text = id;
                    txtClients.Text = clients;
                    txtDetails.Text = contactdetails;
                    txtPO.Text = ponum;
                    txtScope.Text = scope;
                    txtProjectNo.Text = projectno;
                    txtZIG.Text = zigno;
                    txtAmount.Text = amount;
                    txtInvoiceDate.Text = invoicedate;
                    txtStatus.Text = status;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

> Here is the clickbutton to open file cod, the problem this will open only one file and what i want is for each item in selection box to has its own file when select.

```
 private void btnOpenFiles_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;

      openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"c:\Users\Maryam\Desktop\09-SEP -2020.xlsx";
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult)
        {
            string filename = openFileDialog.FileName;
        }
    }
```

> The page display how will look like, what I want is one of those idea(one of them works with me) 1) when select the item, the user can click on button "file" and open that file OR 2)when select the item, the user can click on the hyperlink and the file is open for him. [Screenshot of how it will look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4ehe.png)

Comment: How to store location  in the button?

Comment: Is it possible, once you select record from combobox, the filelocation for that record will appear directly that the user can click it and open it?

Comment: Do you mean to open the selected file using a button? In the `Button.Click` event handler  you can get the currently selected item from the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` property. If you need detailed help, you have to post the code you are using.

Comment: Yes, once the user select an item, the file that linked to that record, the user can open it by clickng openfile. each record has its own file  name. <pre>for example, select record1, the excel file1 will be displayed once user click "openfile" and select record2, the excel file2 will be displayed once user click "openfile" .</pre>

Comment: Look at this line: openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"c:\Users\Maryam\Desktop\09-SEP -2020.xlsx"; you fixed the file path location to only one this file!!

Comment: Yeah, i dont know how to make a file path for every record selected from combobox.

Comment: There must be a unique logical connection between a ComboBox item and the file name. What is that property? For example, is there a "name" or "id" or whatever in your data record item that is included in the file name? For example, "some-file-142.xlsx".

If so, create a global field (a variable outside your methods) and set it with your unique identifier I mentioned, in `comboBox1_SelectionChanged_1`. Then in `btnOpenFiles_Click` use that global field and append it in the file name the way it suits your needs. Something like this: `"some-file-" + _uniqueId + ".xlsx"`

Comment: I have the Id unique (primary key) but also i add insert button to insert new infor, so the ID will change when i insert. for more details about the idea i added above about how it will look like.